# JQuery select next .selector element using .next('.selector')

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li class="select-me"><b>1</b> <span>Click</span></li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li class="select-me"><b>3</b> <span>Click</span></li>
   <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

My JS:

```
$(function() {
   $('ul li span').on('click', function() {
      var previousSelectMe = $(this).parent().prev('.select-me');
      var nextSelectMe = $(this).parent().next('.select-me');

      console.log(nextSelectMe.find('b').text(), previousSelectMe.find('b').text());
   });
});
```

Now my code is slightly different but this is the main logic. The problem I am having is that I can not get the NEXT `.select-me` element because there is non select-me element in the middle. So with above code next element is undefined.

If I changed my HTML structure to:

```
<ul>
   <li class="select-me"><b>1</b> <span>Click</span></li>
   <li class="select-me"><b>3</b> <span>Click</span></li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Works fine & prints `3` for next. When I click on the `Click` item for `3` it gives me correct previous `1`.

Comment: Try `.nextAll('.select-me:first')` and `.prevAll('.select-me:first')`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon so easy. Only 9*2 characters more to type & solves the problem. Genius :D. thanks for your help buddy if you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the next element even if it is not adjacent, you can use that :

```
.nextAll('.select-me:first');
.prevAll('.select-me:first');
```

- [nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/)
- [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/)
- [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)